# 2 buttons in my android layout, only 1 will work

Tags: java, android, android-layout

In the android sdk, I have programmed 2 buttons to bring me to 2 different layouts. However, only the first one I have programmed will work, while the second one will do completely nothing. I will provide the code if you can catch any things I missed, please tell me what you think. This is one of my first applications to run on android, so try to explain your suggestion as simple as you could.

Code:

```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        private final String T = "Settings";
        @Override 
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            settingsButton();
        }
        private final String T2 = "ManualAdd";
        protected void onCreate1(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            feederButton();
        }


        private void settingsButton() {
            Button messageButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Settings);
            View.OnClickListener myListener = new View.OnClickListener() {@
                Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.i(T, "You clicked the settings button!");
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class));
                }
            };
            messageButton.setOnClickListener(myListener);
        }
        private void feederButton() {
            Button feedButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.AddFeeder);
            View.OnClickListener my2ndListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.i(T2, "You clicked the add button!");
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, ManualAdd.class));
                }
            };
            feedButton.setOnClickListener(my2ndListener);
        }
    }
```

Comment: did you add the second activity to the manifest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot make a different `onCreate()` method for *every button* you have. The reason why only one of your Buttons work is because **only** the `onCreate()` method is only called. The system has no idea about `onCreate1()`. To get both of your buttons working change

```
@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    settingsButton();
}
```

to

```
@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    settingsButton();
    feederButton();
}
```

You can completely delete `onCreate1()` from your source code, it is now obsolete.

It would also be a good idea to follow the official [Android "First App"](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html) tutorial instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button Your_Button_Name;
    Button Your_Button_Name;
    Activity activity;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.Your_Layout_Name);

        //In (R.id.Your_Btn_Name) that's the name that you gave your button in the XML
        activity = this;
        Your_Button_Name = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Your_Btn_Name);
        Your_Button_Name = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Your_Btn_Name);
        Your_Button_Name.setOnClickListener(listener);
        Your_Button_Name.setOnClickListener(listener);

    }

    private View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            switch (v.getId()) {
                case (R.id.Your_Btn_Name):
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Your_Layout_Name.class));

                    break;

                case (R.id.Your_Btn_Name):
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Your_Layout_Name.class));

                    break;
            }
        }
    };
}
```